# Yahoo Mail is not allowing the entry of Polish letters

Tags: yahoo-mail, special-characters

In Polish we have letters that need a dot over Z for example. I am able to type them using the keyboard as <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> to yield ż.

I can write it anywhere else but within the Yahoo Mail text. When I type <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> the word is deleted.